So just because gravity "merely" bends space and isn't "really" a force at a distance - isn't it still a thing at a distance?
As a preamble, just for clarity as far as I can remember (I was awfully drunk) I have a degree in physics, math and comp sci: my point is "here's a probably stupid question at the level of person of keen hobbyist interest, rather than, person of minimal interest", so,
My understanding, and I've hearseend this capsulized dozens of times on youtube channels and in popular science books, is that

Einstein and others pointed out that the idea of gravity being "a force" is whacky and problematic, since, it means it acts magically at distances

Einstein came along and sorted out this (and other major issues) by explaining that gravity is not! a force, but rather, what's happening is mass "bends"† space ... voila!


This all sounds fine.
We have utterly not a clue what space is, but that's ok, we're saying that, here's the Sun, and at various points a, b, c we are "curving" "space" in various specific ways, the phrase "curving space" being a storytelling stand in for something like "objects will, as it happens, when moving in a straight line, not do so, they'll move in a not-straight line, at a, b, c."
Great so far.
There's plain NO force, so we no longer have to figure out why forces are magically acting at a distance, no strings attached.
But instead:
are we not now simply, instead, saying "so, the Sun 'bends' (whatever that means) 'space' (whatever that is) . . . and by the way it does so magically at any distance!  But, hooray, we no longer have to worry about force acting magically at a distance!"
What's the deal on this?

† the 3D analogy of "bends" ... tightens, sucks in, compresses, en-gradients, whatever works.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This isn’t an action at a distance. The Einstein Field Equation relates the local change in the curvature to the local stress-energy content of matter. So there is no interaction at a distance. Matter influences curvature locally and the curvature influences neighboring curvature locally too.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
